# reagent: using watchers to keep local component state in sync with global state?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Consider there is a global app-state (reagent)-atom:

```
(defonce state (reagent/atom ["Here" "are" "some" "words"]))
```

This atom get's manipulated/swapped from different places throughout the web app.

Now there is a container, which needs to render the words from `state`. The container itself needs to keep track of some extra data in its own local state, let's say it needs the length of the words.
So in the local state there should be an atom that is in sync with the global state, having a structure like this:

```
[{:word "Here" :length 4}
 {:word "are" :length 3}
 {:word "some" :length 4}
 {:word "words" :length 5}]
```

Which would be rendered e.g. like so:

```
(defn compo []
   (let [local-state ...]
      (fn []
         [:div
            (for [{:keys [word length] @local-state]
               [:div (str word " - " length)])])))
```

How to do this? Would this be a scenario for a watcher `(installed via add-watch` right at the beginning inside the let statement) ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to maintain a separate local atom, if it's supposed to be in sync with the global state at all times. Just use the global state instead, and put the `let` expression inside the rendering function.

```
(defn compo []
  (let [local-data ...]
    [:div
      (for [{:keys [word length] @local-data]
        [:div (str word " - " length)])]))
```

Now the whole body of the render function will get executed each time it gets invoked. Because of that you can use `local-data` to map the global state to what you need for this component.

Hope this helps.

Also, there's another clojurescript framework called [re-frame](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame). It's built on top of reagent and it implements subscribers which are exactly what you might be looking for. You can read more about them [here](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame#subscribe).

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but in your example you don't use global state... I think you mean to use both global and local state, right?

Comment: I mean to just use a ```let``` expression to transform a part of the global state to suit your needs before it gets rendered, instead of creating a new atom. I hope that's clear enough. ```local-state``` in my example isn't an atom anymore, it's just the immutable result of the expression.

Comment: this is wrong implementation. you only can do local state with form-2 and form-3 https://github.com/Day8/re-frame/wiki/Creating-Reagent-Components#form-2--a-function-returning-a-function

Comment: The whole point of this solution is to have no local state. Each time the render function is triggered, it computes the data it needs again and again. I'll update my answer as I see this is causing some confusion. And since you brought up re-frame - its subscribers allow to inject only the part of the global state that's actually used by the rendering function and improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some local reactive state which can be derived from the other state - you could use reagent [reaction](https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent/blob/master/doc/ManagingState.md#reactions).

```
(defonce state (reagent/atom ["Here" "are" "some" "words"]))

(defn count-words-length ...)

(defn compo []
  (let [words-length (reagent.ratom/reaction (count-words-length @state))]
    [:div
      (for [{:keys [word length] @words-length]
        [:div (str word " - " length)])]))
```

In this case, `count-words-length` will re-run reactively every time when `state` atom changes.